# My C++ library has several 3rd party dependencies. Can I make it so others can include only my library in their own projects?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, header, include

I have a library I'm working on that is internal to my organization.  It utilizes Magick++, TBB, and a few other libraries.  My program compiles fine, and I've been able to use it some of my other projects, but it requires that you link it and all of its dependencies into your new project.  Is there a way of having other users in my group simply need to include/link my project without needing to worry about any of the dependencies?

Currently in order to use my library in a new project, cmake needs to use `find_package` and `target_link_libraries` to find and link all of the dependencies for my library.  Is there any way that I can simplify this process so that they don't need to worry about that?  Could I provide a CMake for my library that might simplify this process somehow?  Or is there a way of packaging the headers and binaries from the relevant dependencies into my library's installation when its built?

Comment: Your operating system/distribution surely has package management infrastructure that provides for creation of installable packages that specify its dependencies, so that installing your shared library will also require installation of all of its dependencies, as well. Check your operating system/distribution's documentation for more information.

Comment: conan or vcpkg are the best way to do it. Otherwise you'll have to specify the dependencies in your cmake config file for your library

Comment: Use static libraries?